# Ruby searching through multidimensional array

Tags: ruby, arrays, search, multidimensional-array

Learning the beauty of Ruby code and I was wondering if there is a simple/straightforward to search within a multidimensional array. I have an multi array with 4 indices that contain assorted number. I want to search though each index matching the contents agains another array...seudo codez

```
multi_array = [ [1,3,7], [3,1,4], [1,3,4], [0,9,2]]
numbers_looking_to_match = [1,5,9]
multi_array.each do | elmt |
  elmt.each_with_index do |elmt, idx|
    if elmt == numbers_looking_to_match.each { |e| puts "match" }
  end 
end
```

I want this to return a new multi array with all non matching characters removed for original multi array.

Comment: Are you trying to remove numbers from within each element of multi_array? Or throw out an element of multi_array if it doesn't contain an exact match for numbers_looking_to_match?  Also, do you care about order of numbers in each element?

Comment: What I am trying to do is remove number not matching the number_looking_to_match...so if we look at the multi array and numbers_looking_to_match arrays the return of the function *should* provide me with a result == [[1],[1],[1],[9] but Not limited to one result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [`Array#&`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-26) for intersection,

```
multi_array.map {|a| a & numbers_looking_to_match }
```

Comment: what if the array has mixed types? the first element in my array is a Fixnum and the rest are Arrays or Strings

Answer (score 1):

`multi_array.each { |elem| numbers_looking_to_match.each { |x| elem.delete(x) if elem.include?(x)}` }

Answer (score 1):

To scrub each element of unwanted characters:

```
require 'set'
multi_array=[ [1,3,7], [3,1,4], [1,3,4], [0,9,2]]
numbers_looking_to_match=Set.new([1,5,9])

scrubbed=multi_array.collect{ |el|
  numbers_looking_to_match.intersection(el).to_a
}

puts scrubbed.inspect
# prints [[1], [1], [1], [9]]
```